# Win 7 - 64bit | Intel i5 | GeForce 510 - graphics drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I have a little problem when trying to install graphics drivers for my nVidia GeForce 510.

I have tried downloading the drivers from the nVidia website, they installed without any errors, but in the Windows Hardware management thing, I get:

> Code 37 - Windows could not initialize the appropriate drivers

Specs:

- Acer Aspire M3970
- Intel i5 + Intel HD graphics
- nVidia GeForce 510
- Windows 7 64bit, official version (came pre-installed)

Could it be that I need to disable the Intel HD graphics? If yes, how?

Comment: try this driver: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/70737/en-us

Comment: I have already installed that driver and tried reinstalling

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** disable Intel graphics ([why?](https://superuser.com/a/677146/194694)). Instead, try updating Intel drivers first.

Then reset your BIOS settings to defaults. Some laptop BIOSes have Optimus bugs that causes them to permanently switch to a legacy mode, where NVIDIA GPU is unavailable. Restoring default settings may fix the problem.

Comment: I will try updating the Intel HD drivers and let you know more. Thanks for informing me to not disable them

Comment: I get an error "This program is not compatible with your computer" when I try to install the Intel drivers, I tried different versions

Comment: Where did you download them? Intel's website has terrible download section, getting older drivers from laptop manufacturer's website may be a good option.

Comment: I see, I'll try downloading from Acer's site.

Comment: It didn't help..